# How many gigabyte(internet use) needed for bitcoin mining in a month?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

if I use Antminer s9 full-time in a month, how many gigabyte uses?
I mean what is the internet usage((Download+Upload)) in a month?

comment about duplicate: first of all I want know the usage not bandwidth or speed of my internet, second, your mentioned linked is for near 7 years later. I want know how many gigabyte usage in a month with 14 Th/s. it is only a number which an expert can say, plz do not answer cursory.

Comment: @EricAllam first of all I want know the usage not bandwidth or speed of my internet, second, your mentioned linked is for near 7 years later. I want know how many gigabyte usage in a month with 14 Th/s. it is only a number which an expert can say, plz do not answer cursory.

Comment: You'll have to specify your pool to get an answer.  Your pool, as well as possibly your individual settings, will determine how often you receive work and submit shares, which is the main data usage for pool mining.  (If you're solo mining then the answer is completely different again, as you have to run a full node in that case.)  Your hash rate is irrelevant.